# How do I compress old directories in a shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, directory, tar

As part of a deployment process, I create backup directories in /opt/backup/{backupDirectory}.

Because backups can take significant space when added together, but need to be retained due to policy I would like to compress these individually using a slightly different name.

Inside /opt/backup/ a backupDirectory will have a name similar to {site}-%Y%m%d and contain a directory whose name is an md5 checkSum of the date and time:

```
dateTime=$(date --rfc-3339=seconds);
checkSum=`md5sum <<<"$dateTime" | cut -d" " -f1`;

dateForName=$(date +%Y%m%d);
```

This allows for uniqueness in case of multiple deployments on a single date without getting weird about what I'm check-summing.

So an example looks like /opt/backup/site-20151125/aa55596ecfb369c537cac404af5e23fc/.

I want to tarball the dated directory: site-20151125, into its own tarball, but only if the directory is older than a configurable +mtime.

Here is what I have been trying, but the loop appears to run through subdirectories and I only want one level of depth visible to the script.

logThis is a custom logging function which simply logs a message to a configured file in a predetermined format.

For simplicity in testing, let's set numDaysForCompression to 1.

```
function compressBackups {
    numDaysForCompression=1;
    homeForTheCompressed="/opt/backup/compressed";
    compressedFileName="backup-site-$dateForName-$checkSum.tgz";

    if [[ -d $homeForTheCompressed ]]; then
        logThis "Home for compressed backups already exists.";
        echo "Home for compressed backups already exists.";
    else
        logThis "No home for compressed backups detected.";
        echo "No home for compressed backups detected.";

        logThis  "Creating: $homeForTheCompressed.";
        echo  "Creating: $homeForTheCompressed.";

        mkdir $homeForTheCompressed;
    fi

    logThis "Using $homeForTheCompressed to store backups over $numDaysForCompression days old.";

    datedBackups=($(find -d /opt/backup/site/ -mtime +$numDaysForCompression));
    for individualBackupDirectory in ${datedBackups[@]}
    do
        #tar -cvfz $compressedFileName $individualBackupDirectory;
        echo $individualBackupDirectory;
    done
}
```

Again, this appears to run through, listing every matching directory, and would (I presume) create separate tarballs for each directory and subdirectory, which would not be -bueno-.

I think what I need is to tweak this line:

```
datedBackups=($(find -d /opt/backup/site/ -mtime +$numDaysForCompression));
```

But I am not entirely certain, nor do I believe this is completely optimized. Assistance is welcomed!

Comment: You can limit how far down `find` recurses with the `-maxdepth` argument but that said if you don't need to recurse at all then you could just avoid `find` entirely and just use a glob instead and use `stat`/etc. for the time stuff in the loop. `for iBD in /opt/backup/triplefin/*; do mod=$(stat -c %Y); ...; done`

Comment: Unless you have already set `dateForName` and `checkSum` before you call this function this assignment `compressedFileName="backup-site-$dateForName-$checkSum.tgz";` won't work the way you want.

Comment: Thanks @EtanReisner.

I do set the values at the beginning of the script which has other functions. This is the only function I am having issues with.

Comment: @EtanReisner When I run a similar command to what you suggested as a test, I get the following output.

`for iBD in /opt/backup/site/*; do mod=$(stat -c %Y); echo $iBD; done`
Try 'stat --help' for more information.
/opt/backup/triplefin/microsite-20151118
Try 'stat --help' for more information.
/opt/backup/triplefin/microsite-20151124

Any suggestions on pruning the warning from stat so I only get back what I need to work with?

Comment: Correct. I'm running on Ubuntu server 14.04 with stat v8.21. -c is what it needs based on the man-page, and %Y or %y are both workable to determine age. So those are fine.

However, whenever I run the command stat indicates it's missing an operand:

`stat: missing operand
Try 'stat --help' for more information.
/opt/backup/triplefin/microsite-20151124
`

Comment: Oh, bah... that was stupid. I missed the filename. Sorry. `mod=$(stat -c %Y "$iBD")`

Comment: Oh wow! That's so easy to miss! Should have caught it myself! Brilliant assist sir @EtanReisner! I wish I could move this comment thread to an answer and give you credit!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can limit how far down `find` recurses with the `-maxdepth` argument.

That said if you don't need to recurse at all then you could avoid `find` entirely and use a glob and use `stat`/etc. (for the time stuff) in the loop directly.

Something like:

```
for iBD in /opt/backup/sute/*; do
    mod=$(stat -c %Y)
    # Check "$mod" against current time and your threshold ...
done
```